# Android DDMS tool hangs after selecting a device

Tags: android, ddms

On linux i have an Android ARM emulator running. I wanted to see the log output, so i started ddms on the command line. After ddms opened i selected the device. Then after two or three seconds DDMS freezes.
It freezes only after i select the device.

Does someone know whats the problem here?
Thx.

Comment: You don't need ddms to see the log output, just do 'adb logcat' in a shell.

Comment: Yay, Thanks! That will help for now.

Answer (score 0):

DDMS is now deprecated, as it's output shows:

> The standalone version of DDMS is deprecated.
>   Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead.

Try `monitor` tool instead. And, as @Chris Stratton said, you can always use logcat either as a standalone tool, or as part of your IDE(Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea support it).